# How to prevent increase of table cell while nesting input tag?

Tags: html, angular, html-table, tablecell

I nest `input` tag by condition:

```
<td *ngFor="let cell of row.Persons">

    <span cell.editable === true ">
        <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="cell.PersonCount" autofocus />
    </span>

    <span *ngIf="cell.editable === false " (click)="toggle(cell)">
        {{ cell.PersonCount ? cell.PersonCount : '-' }}
    </span>

</td>
```

The width of table cell `Person` without `input` tag looks like that:
[image]

And when `Person` cell has `input` tag:
[image]

I've tried to set the following style, however there is no result:

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="cell.PersonCount"
       style="display: inline; max-width: 100%; width: inherit; height: 
       inherit;  box-sizing: border-box !important; overflow:hidden;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
       -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important; border: none;" autofocus />
```

My question is **how can I keep size of cell to be the same like there is no `input` tag** (like on the first image)?

I've created [an example at plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9iiXJOKmp2d5aysZLRb0?p=preview), please, see it.

Comment: check the min-width of your input.

Comment: @lexith what value should I set to `min-width`?

Comment: I would probably set width to 100% and min-width to 0

Comment: @lexith setting `min-width:0` does not prevent resizing.

Comment: Mhhhh, can you provide a small reproducable plunkr? Because i came across this behaviour a lot and it was always the minWidth problem, therefore my guess.

Comment: @lexith Here is a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/9iiXJOKmp2d5aysZLRb0?p=preview

Comment: did you using bootstrap in you project ?

Comment: @Chandru yeah, I use `Bootstrap` in my project.

Comment: https://codepen.io/w3core/pen/DjLml?editors=1111 see this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are the dimensions of the input itself. `<input>` elements have an attribute called `size` which defaults to `20`, which means this would behave all the same:

- `<input type="text" />`
- `<input type="text" size="20" />`
- `<input type="text" size="0" />`

Anyhow, the problem still remains if you set `size` to the smallest value (1) because that's still a "hardcoded" size and not relative to any other element.

The only way around would be to set a width (either static or dynamic) to the parent element (your `td`) in both cases, and set your input to `width: 100%`.

I adjusted your [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/I49N7wEXVfbbCIzSqpAb?p=preview) a bit as an example of how you could do it.

Hope it helps.

*P.S: The `min-width` problem i mentioned is a bootstrap thing i think, anyway it only matters if you actually set a width, in this case set min-width to 0 to override the bootstrap defaults.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<td *ngFor="let cell of row.Persons" style="display: inherit;">
    <span *ngIf="cell.editable">
        <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="cell.PersonCount" autofocus style="max-width: 50px;"/>
    </span>
</td>
```